# Algorithm Recurrence formula

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I am reading Algorithms in C++ by Robert Sedgewick. Basic recurrences section it was mentioned as This recurrence arises for a recursive program that loops through the input to eliminate one item
                              Cn = cn-1 + N, for N >=2 with C1 = 1.

Cn is about Nsquare/2.  Evaluating the sum 1 + 2 +...+ N is elementary. in addition to this following statement is mentioned.
          " This result - twice the value sought - consists of  N terms, each of which sums to N +1

I need help in understanding abouve statement what are N terms here and how each sums to
N +1, aslo what does "twice the value sought" means.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think he refers to this basic mathematical trick to calculate that sum. Although, it's difficult to conclude anything from such short passage you cited.

Let's assume `N = 100`. E.g., the sum is `1 + 2 + 3 + .. + 99 + 100`.
Now, let's group pairs of elements with sum `101`: `1 + 100`, `2 + 99`, `3 + 98`, ..., `50 + 51`. That gives us `50` (`N/2`) pairs with sum `101` (`N + 1`) in each: thus the overall sum is `50*101`.

Anyway, could you provide a bit more context to that quote?

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence formula means:

```
C1 = 1
C2 = C1 + 2 = 1 + 2 = 3
C3 = C2 + 3 = 3 + 3 = 6
C4 = C3 + 4 = 6 + 4 = 10
C5 = C4 + 5 = 10 + 5 = 15
etc.
```

But you can also write it directly:
    C5 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15

And then use the old trick:

```
  1 +   2 +   3 + ... + N
+ N + N-1 + N-2 + ... + 1
-------------------------
 (N+1) ...             (N+1)
```

= (N+1) * N

From there we get : 1 + 2 + ... N = N * (N+1) / 2

For the anecdote, the above formula was found by the great mathematician Carl Friedrich Gauss, when he was at school.

From there we can deduce a recursive algorithm is O(N square) and that is probably what Robert Sedgewick is doing.